# ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION Returns After Config Change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, pdf-generation

While I know there are several answered questions regarding this issue, I'm having a bit of a different problem.

I want to be clear that this has been working for me and only after a change to the target framework (4.6.1 to 4.7.2) did it start (again).  Again, no change has been made to the code below.  I've changed the target framework back to 4.6.2 and the problem will not go away.  Further, IIS Express locally, works  but when I publish to my actual production server, it doesn't.

Like everyone else, I have to add double-quotes around my filename (which I did when I originally encountered the problem) and which fixed the problem.  But now, even though I have the double-quote, the problem is still occurring.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{1}.pdf\"; size={0}", outPdfBuffer.Length.ToString(), MyProtocolsInfo.MyProtocols));
```

Again, let me stress, this code WAS WORKING.

I have also tried the following with no success

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + MyProtocolsInfo.MyProtocols + ".pdf\"");
```

I have also tried prepending

```
Response.Clear();
```

I'm at a loss as to what could make this fail even though the code in question was not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  An additional header was being added by the server from another process.